# Подскажите какую технологию использовать

Tags: java, mysql, sql, javafx, jdbc

Обучаюсь Java, хочу написать программу которая принимает от пользователя данные(код), ищет по этому коду в БД товар, и выводит его на экран, при нажатии пользователем кнопки "Купить/Оплатить/Заказать/или т.п.", делает "ЧЕК/Бланк заказа или накладную(не принципиально)", затем удаляет из базы то количество которое пользователь "Заказал"...
Собираюсь использовать:
GUI: Java FX
БД: MySQL или SQLLite?
Java технологии пока получается только JDBC.
Возможно ошибаюсь в своем выборе, подскажите или поправьте в моем выборе.

Comment: SQLLite больше для андроида, берите MySQL или Postgree, изучайте ORM, а там и Хибернейт в помощь. И в конце -концов добавляйте Spring Data.

Comment: Если программа для обучения, то рекомендую не использовать фреймворки, чем больше Java Core на начальном этапе - тем лучше. К тому же самому ORM лучше приступать, хорошо зная JDBC, т.к. любой ORM-фреймворк работает поверх JDBC. Есть особая категория кодеров, которая умеет программировать только "навешиванием аннотаций", не понимая, что происходит под капотом. В 99% их ждёт провал уже на этапе собеседования, не то что в работе над реальным проектом.